# Можно ли получить исходный JS код после выполнения eval которая создает глобальную функцию на странице?

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering, eval

Имеется такая функция.

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('o u(g){b v="w";b p=g.q.l;b h=r(p);h=m(h);b a=h;a=m(a);g.a.l=a;g.x.l=a;b y=g.q.l;z=m(h)}o m(d){b f=d%j;b n=(d-f)/j;d=n+f;e((d>=j)&&(d!=A)&&(d!=B)){f=d%j;n=(d-f)/j;d=n+f}s d}o r(k){k=k.C();b t=k.D;b a=0;E(b i=0;i<t;i++){b c=k.F(i);e((c=="а")||(c=="и")||(c=="с")||(c=="ъ")){a+=1}e((c=="б")||(c=="й")||(c=="т")||(c=="ы")){a+=2}e((c=="в")||(c=="к")||(c=="у")||(c=="ь")){a+=3}e((c=="г")||(c=="л")||(c=="ф")||(c=="э")){a+=4}e((c=="д")||(c=="м")||(c=="х")||(c=="ю")){a+=5}e((c=="е")||(c=="н")||(c=="ц")||(c=="я")){a+=6}e((c=="ё")||(c=="о")||(c=="ч")){a+=7}e((c=="ж")||(c=="п")||(c=="ш")){a+=8}e((c=="з")||(c=="р")||(c=="щ")){a+=9}}s a}',42,42,'||||||||||nameNumber|var||mynumber|if|n2|form|f1||10|fname|value|reduceit|n1|function|ffirst|first|calcName|return|namelength|calcNumbers|bDoDestiny|TRUE|lc|ffirst1|f11|11|22|toLowerCase|length|for|charAt'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

После выполнения на странице, ее можно вызвать так.

```
onclick="calcNumbers(this.form);"
```

Как получить код функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, r) {
  e = function(c) {
    return (c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
  };
  if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
    while (c--) r[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c);
    k = [function(e) {
      return r[e]
    }];
    e = function() {
      return '\\w+'
    };
    c = 1
  };
  while (c--)
    if (k[c]) p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]);
  return p
}('o u(g){b v="w";b p=g.q.l;b h=r(p);h=m(h);b a=h;a=m(a);g.a.l=a;g.x.l=a;b y=g.q.l;z=m(h)}o m(d){b f=d%j;b n=(d-f)/j;d=n+f;e((d>=j)&&(d!=A)&&(d!=B)){f=d%j;n=(d-f)/j;d=n+f}s d}o r(k){k=k.C();b t=k.D;b a=0;E(b i=0;i<t;i++){b c=k.F(i);e((c=="а")||(c=="и")||(c=="с")||(c=="ъ")){a+=1}e((c=="б")||(c=="й")||(c=="т")||(c=="ы")){a+=2}e((c=="в")||(c=="к")||(c=="у")||(c=="ь")){a+=3}e((c=="г")||(c=="л")||(c=="ф")||(c=="э")){a+=4}e((c=="д")||(c=="м")||(c=="х")||(c=="ю")){a+=5}e((c=="е")||(c=="н")||(c=="ц")||(c=="я")){a+=6}e((c=="ё")||(c=="о")||(c=="ч")){a+=7}e((c=="ж")||(c=="п")||(c=="ш")){a+=8}e((c=="з")||(c=="р")||(c=="щ")){a+=9}}s a}', 42, 42, '||||||||||nameNumber|var||mynumber|if|n2|form|f1||10|fname|value|reduceit|n1|function|ffirst|first|calcName|return|namelength|calcNumbers|bDoDestiny|TRUE|lc|ffirst1|f11|11|22|toLowerCase|length|for|charAt'.split('|'), 0, {}));

console.log(calcNumbers.toString());
```

Comment: Да уже получил, но просто заменив eval на console.log